# How to customize a toolbar added from the palette in android studio

Tags: android, themes, toolbar

Every tutorial out there is on how to CREATE a toolbar rather than on how to add one from the palette itself and then customizing it. What's the difference and the upsides/downsides between both? And for the original question, how do I customize a toolbar added from the palette?

Comment: customize new xml file for toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a toolbar is separately adding a toolbar.xml file where you customize it based on your needs. For example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

By this method you can customize the toolbar based on your needs to add imageview, textview or any other theme based customization. Now doing this, you have to declare the toolbar in each of your xml activity file by

```
<include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>
```

Also, you need to declare it in onCreate of each activity like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            }
            toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

> **Note: You can customize your toolbar from palette by going to values->
>   styles.xml file**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondary</item>
```

Instead of NoActionBar you can customize from the available theme palettes. Check the official documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html) here for more details.

> **Note: Upsides of using the custom theme is you can customize it based
>   on your need; downside that you have to declare everywhere which
>   consumes time. Upside of using the theme provided by android studio is
>   you can build your app faster and easier but customizations are
>   limited.**

Comment: Thank you, that cleared things up.

Comment: glad it helped cheers!